# How to update java version for teamcity

Tags: ubuntu, java, updates, teamcity

We have a ubuntu server with teamcity installed.

Teamcity is warning us that the java version that's using is old. The message is

```
This TeamCity server is using a deprecated version of Java (8). Please upgrade Java as future versions of TeamCity will be incompatible with Java 8.
```

I've downloaded the package `jdk-17.0.10_linux-x64_bin.deb` from oracle web site, and I've installed it with `sudo dpkg -i jdk-17.0.10_linux-x64_bin.deb`. Then, I've run the command

```
sudo update-java-alternatives --set jdk-17-oracle-x64
```

I've rebooting the server, and the command `java -version` gives to me

```
java version "17.0.10" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.10+11-LTS-240, mixed mode, sharing)
```

So it seems ok. But Teamcity is complaining that the version is yet the old one. And also other variables like `$J2REDIR` seems to point to the old installation

```
$ echo $J2REDIR
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

What I'm doing wrong? How can I set correctly the java version for Teamcity?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot... 22.04 64 bit.

Comment: Your `update-alternatives` is half configured. I suggest removing this Deb and installing the package from Ubuntu repository

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion.